# Create a custom meta description for WordPress Blogs page

Tags: wordpress, meta

I want to write a custom meta description for my WordPress blog page. I don't have a custom front page, the posts page is the front page. I downloaded SEO by Yoast and added what I want to the Meta description template field on the Home Tab in the Titles and Meta's section of the plug-in, but that hasn't accomplished what I wanted. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The word press site details meta data and setting meta tags.

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress

There are also plugins available if you need more advanced functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the posts page is the front page, so you should edit description on the post page in Yoast SEO section.

[image: Post edit page, Yoast SEO section]